# no power notifications with i3wm

Tags: power-management, notification, notify-osd, i3-wm

I use Ubuntu 12.10, but changed to the i3 window manger. It works great, but I do not get the normal "low power" notification. Notify OSD works as expected (I tested it per notify-send).

How can I activate low power notifications?

AFAIK ubuntu uses the gnome-power-manager (for power notifications), but this application isn't installed yet.. this is strange because If I login with unity as wm anything works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following line to `~/.xsession` and run i3wm from lightdm as session:

```
/usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daemon &
```

The xsession file should be executable.

This get for me (12.04!) the power events for lid close, power button etc. working and should hence catch to power notification for low power.